# How to play multiple footstep sounds without blocking animations?

Tags: swift, multithreading, animation, queue

Am coding a game with scenes that a man runs in different distance and durations. Due to different running speeds and durations(0.009sec, 0.02sec, 0.05sec...), it's not a good way to playing a sound with multiple steps inside. By now, It is set to play one step sound when footstep moves once.

I tried the following code:

1. Steps play one by one, but the animation thread blocked. Then man runs unsmoothly

   ```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Sound.shared.play(.step)
    }
   ```
2. The animation goes smoothly, but some step sounds missing, it could be two or more sounds play at the same time, so they sound like one step sound.

   ```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        Sound.shared.play(.step)
    }
   ```
3. Same as the second

   ```
    let soundQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "soundQueue", qos: .default, attributes: [.concurrent], autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: nil)
    soundQueue.async {
        Sound.shared.play(.step)
    }
   ```

**Supplement Info:** First 30 step sounds `AVAudioPlayer` are stored in an array so that sounds can be played in a fast way.

```
func playSound(_ type: SoundType) {
    switch type {
    case .key:
    case .step:
        self.doPlayStepSound()
    //....
    default:
        break
}

var stepPlayerArr = [AVAudioPlayer?]()
func doPlayStepSound() {
    if stepCount >= 30 {
        stepCount = 0
    }        
    if let player = stepPlayerArr[stepCount] {
        player.play()
    }
    stepCount += 1
}
```

How can I play each step sound when the man's footstep moves without blocking the animations?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `isPlaying` property of the `AVAudioPlayer` to check that there isn't a walking sound being played already (and if so don't play the sound) in order to fix the problem in 2 and 3.

Comment: @TheSwiftCoder Sorry I didn't make the question clear. `AVAudioPlayer` are stored in an array before the sounds are played. I have added supplement information.